# What does undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 mean in C?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int first;
int second;
int third;
float average=0.0;

    printf ("This program will find the average of 3 numbers.\n");
    delay(1000);
    printf ("Type the first number.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &first);
    printf ("Type the second number.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &second);
    printf ("Type the third number.\n");
    scanf ("%d", &third);
    average = (first+second+third)/2.0;
    printf ("The average of %d, %d, and %d is %.3f\n", first, second, third, average);

return (0);
}
```

When I use gcc to compile it says

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_delay", referenced from:
      _main in cc62F0GD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am a beginner in coding. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Undefined symbol <function> first referenced in file <file>" link error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036321/undefined-symbol-function-first-referenced-in-file-file-link-error)

Comment: @H2CO3 no! there is some problem with `delay()` I have also suffered in old time, I don't know but on linux we use `sleep()` , previously (7-8 year back I was even use to call `delay()` in Redhat) but now presently in my ubuntu system I don't have `delay()` it generally present in `dos.h` on window base system

Comment: even i remember using stdlib.h i tried now and its not working.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Huh? In C, header files have nothing to do with linker errors.

Comment: @H2CO3 what I mean to complete answer the question, this is very important that with gcc use sleep() thats all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since the code is being run on linux environment you can use **sleep** instead of **delay**. The header file is **unistd.h**.

Answer (score 1):

You need  to include `#include<stdlib.h>` file in your code for `delay()` function, its not defined in `stdio.h`

But I suggest don't use it, instead use what most Unix based operating system suggests [`unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) function from `#include <unistd.h>`.

[read don't use delay()](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/139729-delay-function-c-number-seconds.html)

Comment: Its in stdlib.h girijesh

Comment: Girijesh sorry it doesnt seem to work , i had used the same during my turbo c days .i guess time.h also supports the function.

Comment: i don't have turbo c and its not working on visual studio 2010. I searched and dos.h has delay defined . But its better to use sleep instead of busy wait on delay.Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thats why I answered this question, its remind me the days I just shifted to linux from windos-98. -- now I don't know which is most new window I think window-vista

Answer (score 1):

use `sleep()` instead of delay()

EX : `sleep(1)` = 1 second delay

Answer (score 0):

Here the error you got is form loader

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am not sure but check for the symbol present in your executable.

Use **nm** command to check the symbole present in your executable.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm

`delay()` in not supported in `GCC` use `sleep()`

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html

Comment: stdlib.h not contain delay().

Comment: can you post the updated link of stdlib.h, because i using  newer c libraries there delay() not available.

Comment: its ok. sorry for misunderstanding.